# Cómo se dice en español "Women's Network"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico

Cómo se dice en español "Women's Network"?

Yo lo traduciría como `Grupo de Mujeres` o `Red de Grupo de Mujeres`, pero no suena del todo bien.

Comment: Are you talking about a network comprised of women? Or are you talking about a network owned by or used by women? They would take different translations. Or are you talking about a specific, proper noun? Once you clarify the question a bit, please flag for moderator attention to have the question re-opened.

Answer (score 8):

"*Red de Grupo* de Mujeres" suena redundante. "Red de mujeres" es la mejor opción ya que una *red* tiene connotaciones que un grupo, asociación, liga, comunidad, etc. no tienen. Puedes añadir adjetivos para describir el tipo de red:

> Red **profesional** de mujeres
>
> Red profesional para mujeres directivas
>
> Red **social** de Madres en MiCiudad
>
> Red **española/chilena/salvadoreña** de mujeres *que tienen esto y lo otro en común*

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about a network in the ABC/CBS/NBC/MTV/HBO sense, it would be «El canal de la mujer».